# How to fix npx prisma init error for node 32

Tags: prisma

I'm using Node 32-bit on Windows 11 Pro x64. I'm following the "Start from scratch" guide on your website. When I type npx prisma init I get the follow error:

> Error: The default query engine type (Node-API, "library") is
> currently not supported for 32bit Node. Please set engineType =
> "binary" in the "generator" block of your "schema.prisma" file (or use
> the environment variables "PRISMA_CLIENT_ENGINE_TYPE=binary" and/or
> "PRISMA_CLI_QUERY_ENGINE_TYPE=binary".)

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue. see this open [issue](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/11781). The Prisma team is working on a fix for it. As a workaround, you can upgrade to a 64-bit Node version.

Comment: it's been a year now, the same issue still persist? I am facing the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, remove node.js and re setup node.js, it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and I am able to resolve the issue by uninstalling 32 bit version and installing new version with 64 bit version